# Keeping a UI functional while posting json async in C# with .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm still really new to asynchronous programming.  I have a relatively simple program that sends json and receives json back.  The program itself works fine but I'm working on trying to learn how to make the ui remain responsive.  When I learned about async and await in .net 4.5 it seemed like at last there is a method of multithreading that makes sense to me.  What I did seems to be partially successful.  But there's still moments when my program still becomes unresponsive for a short time.  I fear that most of the problem lies in the following piece of code but I don't exactly understand why.

The complete code for the communications layer can be found here:
https://github.com/Jazzeroki/JazzTools/blob/master/Jazz%20Tools/LEWrapper/LEWrapper.cs

The code for the UI can be found here:
https://github.com/Jazzeroki/JazzTools/blob/master/Jazz%20Tools/MainForm.cs

The code I'm mainly concerned about is below.  And yes I know I should put a try block in here.  The empty while loop at the start of the code should never currently be entered into by my program as it only ever needs to make about 3-4 rpc requests to perform its job.

```
    private async void PostAsync(string url, JsonTextWriter json)
    {
        while (rpcCount > 50)
        { }//This creates the wait time until rpc count is reset.
        string server = serverURL + url;
        json.AutoComplete();
        string jsonToSend = json.ToString();
        //if (jsonToSend == null)
           // MessageBox.Show("json error " + jsonToSend);
        WriteStringToLog("request");
        WriteStringToLog(jsonToSend);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(server, new StringContent(jsonToSend));
        //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        WriteStringToLog("response");
        WriteStringToLog(responseFromServer);

        if (ServerResponseEvent != null) //deserializes the server response and passes it out as an event.
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Response r = js.Deserialize<Response>(responseFromServer);
            if (r.id == 101)
            {
                sessionID = r.result.session_id;
                //Console.WriteLine(sessionID);
            }

            ServerResponseEvent(this, r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That tight while loop is messy. Where is rpcCount handled and why do you need that anyway? Can you try with only the FIRST await?

Comment: Can you replace the first while loop with a [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx)?

Comment: I'll have to explore that option as until now I'd never heard of it.  Currently to go along with that while loop I have a a timer running that resets the count back to 0 every 60 seconds.

Comment: If you use Async Methods and write await directly before it, you are basically using synchron methods. Because if with await you are telling, that you want till i.e. PostAsync has completed. This means you are stuck there till the method is finished, like in any synchron method, too. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx for more information

Comment: My basic program structure works like so.  The UI makes calls to my API wrapper called lewrapper, and then those methods are the ones that call the method I posted above.  Currently the lewrapper methods are not marked with async.  It's those that I'm considering changing to async as well.

Comment: I don't see any blocking in that code, unless you have some situation that isn't apparent from the code (e.g., a very large JSON response). Off-topic remarks: You should use `async Task` instead of `async void` - and you may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) helpful. Prefer `SemaphoreSlim` or `DefaultConnectionLimit` over an empty `while` loop. Also, consider switching to [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) - MS uses JSON.NET now in their project templates.

Comment: Here's what I have working along with that while loop.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary would I see better performance if I did return a task rather than keeping the method void.  Especially since I'm working with a gui I figured it would be better to send out the server replies in events rather than as a return type.

Comment: @rene Here's where rpc count is handled in a timer event that fires every 60 seconds '        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpcCount = 0;//resets rpc count to 0 every 60 seconds                    
        }'  Do you by chance have an example of how I could do that with the semaphoreslim.  The point of the loop is purely to keep me from making more than 50 requests in a minute.  The server limit is set to 60.

Comment: Returning `Task` is about semantics, not performance. You could try acquiring the `SemaphoreSlim` instead of the `while` loop and have your timer release it `50 - CurrentCount` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't see any blocking in that code, unless you have some situation that isn't apparent from the code (e.g., a very large JSON response). Off-topic remarks: You should use async Task instead of async void - and you may find my async/await intro and MSDN article helpful. Prefer SemaphoreSlim or DefaultConnectionLimit over an empty while loop. Also, consider switching to JSON.NET - MS uses JSON.NET now in their project templates. – Stephen Cleary Jun 2 at 12:52